# Let's play tag!

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge, lateral-thinking

I have a short and bitter-sweet riddle for the community this evening. As always, I hope you enjoy it; good luck!

---

I want to play a game of tag; however, there are some very important rules:

- We both start at the same point.

  - You cannot tag until the third turn or greater.
- Each turn you take one step.
- Each turn I double the number of steps I take.

  - Our stride is exactly the same.
- We travel in a straight line.
- We both take one initial step.
- Our game is played on an infinitely flat plane
- All steps are forwards, never backwards.

  - Assume we are infinitely traveling in a straight line.

---

Can you tag me?

---

Please explain your answer.

Hint:

> Your step is on top, mine on bottom. Please note the `math` tag.
>  $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{32}...$

Comment: Can paths be different? Will you try your best not to get caught, or will you take a path where you can get caught?

Comment: @KradCigol I've updated my post to clarify this question and another.

Comment: Are all steps the same length? Are the turns sequential? Each turn is a straight line, but can you reorient between turns?

Comment: I'm confused by both parties starting at the same point. If we're next to each other, hasn't the tagger already won?

Comment: Can I tag you on, or after the third turn? That changes things significantly. If I can tag you at the start of the third turn, that's easy

Comment: Your hint makes it sound like you halve your number of steps each turn rather than double them...?

Comment: What is the meaning of "our stride is same"?

Comment: @AHKieran Let me clarify the hint with an update to make it more readable.

Comment: @athin This means we move the same distance per step; for example, if one step for you allows you to travel one meter, then one step for me is also equal to one meter.

Comment: Can you adjust your strides between turns? Or is reaching with your arm when you're close but not at the exact same position as your friend allowed?

Comment: @Nautilus ***TAG YOU'RE IT!***

Comment: May I know why it is bitter sweet? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if we both go

> infinitely many times

then your position will be

> $x = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \dots$
>  $x = 1 + 2(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \dots)$
>  $x = 1+2x$
>  $x = -\frac{1}{2}$

and my position will be

> $1+1+1+1+1+\dots= -\frac{1}{2}$, shown by [Dirichlet regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

hence

> I tag you.

Comment: -1 As I argue in [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79646/294), the naive approaches that give $\sum_{x}^{\infty} n^2$ and $\sum_{x}^{\infty} n$ equal to $\infty$ are still correct in some contexts, and those contexts are actually the more reasonable approaches for this puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> Yes.

We can do this because:

> Geometry. If we were on a plane, you would escape, but if we were on a non-Euclidean surface (like a torus or a sphere) you would come up to me from behind and I could tag you. Since earth is a sphere, this seems to be a safe assumption. This also justifies the knowledge tag.

Comment: Ahhh, nice adjustment; you're close with your thinking, serves me right for not thinking about lateral solutions. The real question is, would I escape, even if the plane is infinite? This is definitely a suitable answer to the way the question was originally phrased so don't remove the edit, just edit with a new guess. I'll be awarding $+50$ bounty for thinking outside the box with your spheroid solution.

Comment: @PerpetualJ: Thanks! In the infinite plane - straight line case, it does seem like you’ll escape. I’ll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> Yes. Either A tags B before the game starts,

or

> A's steps are twice as long as B's, and so tag occurs at the end of round 1.

Comment: Very good attempt, but note the knowledge tag. :) +1 for taking the same route my daughter tries every time! HAHA

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Yes

Why?

> I have really long arms

Answer (score 3):

It's not as sensational as the other answers, but there's a genuine, mathematically sound argument to be made that the answer is simply

> No.

The distance $d_{you}$ you've traveled after $n$ turns is $d_{you} = n^2$, and the distance $d_{me}$ I've traveled is $d_{me} = n$.

> Using [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $O(n^2)$ grows faster than $O(n)$, meaning I will never catch you.

One important thing to note that the accepted answer fails to account for:

> While $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ are both equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ based on certain mathematical arguments, the naive approaches that argue that they both grow without bound are still valid in other contexts - and I would argue those contexts are the ones that apply to our puzzle here. See the Wikipedia articles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_4_%2B_8_%2B_%E2%8B%AF and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which say: "Therefore, any totally regular summation method [for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2$] gives a sum of infinity," and, "In the context of the extended real number line, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = \infty$, since its sequence of partial sums increases monotonically without bound."

The reason this is the more appropriate way to approach the puzzle is

> At any given moment in our game, we'll have only played for a finite amount of time. The game will continue without end forever, but the amount of time we'll have played at any moment is arbitrarily large, which is *not* the same thing as infinite. [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/should-the-angels-play-their-game) and [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178675/how-long-would-it-take-to-guess-an-arbitrary-integer-or-real-number) I asked a few years ago explore the distinction and show some of its consequences.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer! My puzzle was technically focused on convergence of the reciprocals of powers of two where starting from 1, as $n$ steps approaches infinity, we converge on 2. $1, 1.5, 1.75, 1.875, 1.9375...$

Comment: @PerpetualJ I don't think that convergence has any useful meaning in your puzzle. The fraction $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is the fraction of the distance you travel that I travel on turn $n$. It makes no meaningful sense to sum up those fractions. What would the sum represent?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> yes

Explanation:

> you did not mention what type of geometric plane so it  might be curved plane where one meet again

Answer (score 2):

Kinda lame, but

> Yes, if you have low stamina and takes some breaks?

Answer (score 1):

You say it's an infinite plane so:

> Let's take a well known graph that stretches off to infinity; $y = \frac{1}{x}$
>  [image]
>  As the values in x reach positive infinity, they become closer and closer to y = 0, until eventually it flips over to negative y, and the x becomes negative infinity, where the x values then increase to near y = 0.
>
>  One could liken this graph to your problem, I believe that as the number of steps taken doubles every time, it would go from a positively infinite number back to negatively infinite, and eventually catch back up again with the other player who only moves 1 step at a time.